# How to use System::Call to call WindowFromPoint windows API function

Tags: winapi, nsis

How do you pass a POINT struct to [WindowFromPoint()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in system plugin syntax?

Answer (score 2):

```
System::Alloc 8
Pop $0
System::Call 'USER32::GetCursorPos(ir0)'
System::Call '*$0(i.r8,i.r9)'
System::Free $0
System::Call 'USER32::WindowFromPoint(ir8,ir9)i.r1'
System::Call 'USER32::GetClassName(ir1,t.r2,i ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN})'
MessageBox mb_ok "$8x$9: $1=$2"
```